# PHP - What is the difference between a class and a function?

Tags: php, function, class

What is the difference between a PHP class and a function? Because I saw this code:

The class:

```
$scclass = new SystemControl();
```

The function:

```
$scfunction = SystemControl();
```

The only difference I can see is the the class has the word "new" in front of it.

Comment: Um... everything? Try looking at the definition, you'll see a HUGE difference.

Comment: what's the difference between a hammer and a hardware store? a function is a tool. a class is a collection of functions that are now called "methods".

Comment: Your question is too general. Back to basics for you. Read this, then ask us what specifically you do not understand. -> http://www.php.net/manual/en/

Comment: @crafter I'm actually posting this for newbies.

Comment: @MarcB I'm actually posting this for newbies.

Comment: @Niet I'm actually posting this for newbies.

Comment: @Me123 I have never heard a newbie ask this question. Never.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class is something which usually gather several of functions to structure up the code. A function is something to structure up your code so you can reuse it. Both these together provide a structure which helps decreasing redundancy and making coding alot easier.

Answer (score 1):

A class is a collection of objects and functions . a class can be we derived and we can reuse it many times . a function do the same thing but we can't derive the contents of a function to a new function.